# What is an optimal method for isolating unrelated sets of data in neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using neo4j to contain temporary datasets from different source systems.  My data consists of a few parent objects which each contain ~4-7 layers of child objects of varying types.  Total object count per dataset varies between 2,000 and 1.5 million. I'm using the python py2neo library, which has had good performance both during the data creation phase, and for passing through cypher queries for reporting.

I'd like to isolate datasets from unrelated systems for querying and purging purposes, but I'm worried about performance.  I have a few ideas, but it's not clear to me which are the most likely to be viable.

1. The easiest to implement (for my code) would be a top-level "project" object. That project object would then have a few direct children (via a relationship) and many indirect children.  I'm worried that when I want to filter by project, I'll have to use a relationship wildcard `MATCH (pr:project)<-[:IN_PROJECT*7]-(c:child_object)` distance, which seems to very expensive query-wise.
2. I could also make a direct relationship between the project object and every other object in the project. `MATCH (pr:project)<-[:IN_PROJECT]-(c:child_object)`This should be easier for writing queries, but I don't know what might happen when I have a single object with potentially millions of relationships.
3. Finally, I could set a project-id property on every single object in the dataset. `MATCH (c:child_object {project-id:"A1B2C3"})` It seems to be a wasteful solution, but I think it might be better performance wise in the graph DB model.

*Apologies if I mangled the sample Cypher queries / neo4j terminology.  I set aside this project for 6 weeks, and I'm a little rusty.*

Comment: Funnily enough, the third openCypher Implementers Meeting, [OCIM3](http://www.opencypher.org/event/2017/11/13/ocim3/) was taking place today in France. The main topic of the event was the handling of "Multiple Graphs", which will give a nice way to handle this issue. Until then, you're stuck with workarounds. I'll add my preferred way in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a finite set of datasets, you should consider using a dedicated label to specify the data source. In Neo4j's property graph data model, a node is allowed to have [multiple labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels).

```
MATCH (c:child_object:DataSourceA)
```

Labels are always indexed, so performance should be better than that of your proposals 1-3. I also think this is a more elegant solution -- however, it will get tricky if you do not know the number of data sets up front. In the latter case, you might use something like

```
MATCH (c:child_object)
WHERE 'DataSourceA' IN labels(c)
```

But this is more like a "full table scan", so performance-wise, you'll be better off using your approach 3 and building an index on `project-id`.

Comment: That's interesting. I had forgotten that multiple labels are allowed, as I didn't have a relevant use case when I first started learning neo4j.  I'll have to see how much hassle it would be to discover these unknown labels at runtime.  Perhaps give them all the same prefix so I can identify them?  Have to see how friendly py2neo will be with multi-labels as well.

Comment: Well labels are easy to discover: the query `MATCH (n) UNWIND labels(n) AS label RETURN DISTINCT label` should do the trick.

Comment: After some experimentation, I think I'm going to use the property method (#3).  I realized that I also need to filter my relationships, and when I'm doing ad-hoc queries in neo's basic web interface, seeing the property on all returned objects and relationships makes troubleshooting my code a bit easier.

Comment: I agree that the web interface does not handle multiple labels very well. One trick that I used to work around that is to change different size to represent the data source and colours to represent the label that defines the type of the node.